# Borrowed local variable in nested lambda

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a list of CSV files and I want to produce an iterator over the lines of all files. I'm thus using `flat_map()`:

```
extern crate csv;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs;

// simple struct used by the csv crate to deserialize the csv line into this Value
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
pub struct Value {
    pub id: String,
}

// I have an iterator over some csv files, 
// I want an iterator of all the lines of all the files
fn do_stuff<I>(files: I)
    where I: Iterator<Item = std::path::PathBuf>
{
    let iter = files.flat_map(|f| {
        let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_file(f).unwrap().has_headers(false);

        rdr.decode()  // <- decode() takes rdr by ref
            .map(|r| {
            let b: Value = r.unwrap();
            b.id //takes some values
        })
    });
    // do stuff with iter
}

fn main() {
    let paths: std::fs::ReadDir = fs::read_dir(".").unwrap();
    do_stuff(paths.map(|p| p.unwrap().path()));
}
```

However, the borrow checker is not happy with this:

```
error: `rdr` does not live long enough
rdr.decode().map(|r| {
^~~
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 22:7...
});
//do stuff with iter
}
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 16:76
let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_file(f).unwrap().has_headers(false);

rdr.decode().map(|r| {
   let b: Value = r.unwrap();
   b.id
})
```

The 2 used lambda (the one in `flat_map` and the one in `map`) do not capture other variables, I thus don't really understand why the local `rdr` needs to live that long.

Well the `decode` function takes a ref on `rdr`, thus it seems `map` needs an owning ref to `rdr`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slightly finicky, but makes sense with Rust's rules. The closure passed to `flat_map` is a function that **returns** an iterator, which is then drained within the `flat_map` iterator. What's happening is that the iterator `decode` relies on a reference to `rdr` being alive, but `rdr` is dropped at the end of the closure!

```
|f| {
        let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_file(f).unwrap().has_headers(false);

        rdr.decode()  // <- decode() takes rdr by ref
            .map(|r| {
            let b: Value = r.unwrap();
            b.id //takes some values
        } // <--- Returns this iterator, which requires &'a mut rdr
 } // <--- rdr dropped here
 // <--- Uh oh, now we can't use the decoder, since rdr doesn't exist
```

The easiest workaround is:

```
 let v: Vec<_> = rdr.decode().map(...).collect();
 v
```

This returns a vector, which is iterated over by `flat_map`. It's probably not the most performant solution, but it's simple.

Another solution would be to write your own `struct` that takes `csv::Reader` by value, and implements `Iterator` like so:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<WhateverType> {
    self.rdr.decode().next().and_then(|v| {
        v.unwrap().id
    })
}
```

Then you'd want to do  something like:

```
|f| {
    let rdr = csv::Reader::from_file(f).unwrap().has_headers(false);

    MyIterator::new(rdr)
}
```